# Sending all output from "yesod test" to the console

Tags: haskell, testing, io, yesod

Is there any way to have `yesod test` send all output to the console instead of just the test results?

I would like the output that normally goes to `dist/test/MyApp-0.1.0-test.log` to interlace with the test "PASSES" and "FAILURES". I sometimes place `liftIO $ print` expressions in my code during debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted an issue to the cabal bug tracker as suggested by Michael Snoyman, and this is the response that I got:

> As of 1.20 we do support streaming output to stdout using
>   --show-details=streaming (IIRC.)

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

`yesod test` uses `cabal test` under the surface. AFAICT, there's no way to get `cabal test` to send stdout to the console, so unfortunately I don't think `yesod test` can do this either. Personally, I think this would be a great addition to both `cabal test` and `yesod test`. If you want to pursue this, could you open a feature request on [the cabal issue tracker](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/new)?

Comment: I submitted an issue. Thanks.